# Not sure how to avoid this ClassCastException

Tags: java

The following code throws a ClassCastException. The collection in question actually does hold `ArrayList<String>`.

```
HashMap listing = (HashMap) data.get(s);
Collection<ArrayList<String>> collection = listing.entrySet();

int count = 0;


for ( ArrayList al : collection ) // exception occurs here
{
    count += al.size();
}
```

I am assuming that this must be converted to Object and

a) I can't seem to figure out how to convert from Object to ArrayList properly

b) I'm not even sure if thats the issue..

Perhaps someone can provide some insight?

Edit: HashMap listing is a `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>`

Comment: It would help if you showed us the actual exception stacktrace and showed us the line on which it occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has problem in second line
`listing.entrySet()` always return `Set<MapEntry<Key,Value>>`
That cannot be casted to `Collection<ArrayList<String>>` even though set is a subtype of collection because the generics are differ.

And then in the HashMap(listing) what is the type of key and value?

Comment: what? Set is a collection and as such can be casted to collection!!. You are right but used wrong words:)

Comment: Changing .entrySet() to .values() was what I needed. That returns a set <ArrayList<String> that I could cast to the collection.

Answer (score 1):

`HashMap.entrySet()` returns `Set<Map.Entry<K,V>>`.  This is not compatible with `Collection<ArrayList<String>>`.

As a side note, your HashMap is a raw type and should be parameterized.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most pluasible place where the exception is occuring is at the following line :
**HashMap listing = (HashMap) data.get(s);**

Are you sure data.get(s) is suppose to return hashmap.

Also entrySet returns a set that is incompatible incompatible to your assignment.